# terms_description and admin problem

Tags: archives, terms

Hey hi,
I am using a piece of code, where with help of it I can display the description of the term to my archives page.
My idea of doing this is simple, I have MBA website and I have 3 custom-taxonomies with 1000's of terms in each,
for-eg:- I have a term mba-in-accounts, so its description will be displayed on the archive page of mba-in-accounts,

But now the main problem is, this description comes well, but it is just displayed to logged in users
I want to make it display to all users who visits my website,
I am using this code to display

```
 <?php 
                if ( is_tax( 'location' ) ) {
                    echo term_description();
                }
                elseif (is_tax('mba_courses')){
                    echo term_description();
                }
                elseif (is_tax('duration')){
                    echo term_description();
                }

                ?>
```

How can I make it display to all users,
and I am also using [allow-html-in-category-descriptions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/) plugin to enable HTML in description box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in [`term_description()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description) and deeper (that I see) that checks for user.

You can try this and see if it returns [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Error) that might make `term_description()` return empty string:

```
get_term_field( 'description', $term, $taxonomy )
```

Comment: how to check for error using `wp_error` and if this fails is there any way to display the terms description to all users?

Comment: @ntechi I had linked to documentation. I have no idea about _any way_ without knowing what is broken.

Comment: after around 1/2 hour now the description is viewed to everyone.
Hows this possible?

Comment: @ntechi likely it was cached and logged in users were getting non-cached version.